# Timestamp: check if it has been 30 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have setup this code, and it does not seem to be working. Basically I put a timestamp in the database, and whenever someone tries to submit something, I check their IP and then the last time they submitted with the timestamp Basically I need to make sure that it has been MORE that 30 minutes before they can post. Here is the code I have soo far...

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$chkquery = "SELECT * FROM faucet where ip='$ip' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;";
$chk = mysql_query($chkquery) or die($chkquery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($chk, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $timestamp = $row['timestamp'];
}
$timenow = time();
$chktime = strtotime($timestamp);
if($chktime <= ($timenow - 1800)) {
    echo "Yay! It has been 30 minutes!";
} else {
    echo "Wait! Its not been 30 minutes";
}
```

Is there anything I need to change/fix to get this to work? Thanks a lot for the help! The if statement might be reversed, but IDK, and also I end up with Yay! no matter what time it is...

Comment: what happen when echo `$timenow ` and `$chktime`..?

Comment: I get this http://puu.sh/4mOnh.png $timenow is on the top and $chktime is underneath it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not safe to rely on  `strtotime()` as it is defined by the system's timezone settings.
You should adjust `date.timezone setting` or use the `date_default_timezone_set()` 
for example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
...

if($timenow - $chktime >= 1800) {
    echo "Yay! It has been 30 minutes!";
} else {
    echo "Wait! Its not been 30 minutes";
}
```

EDIT: add the remaining time

```
$time_diff = $timenow - $chktime;
if( $time_diff >= 1800) {
    echo "Yay! It has been 30 minutes!";

} else {
    $remaining = (1800 - $time_diff );
    echo "Wait! Its not been 30 minutes\n";
    echo "please come back in ".date ( "i:s" , $remaining)." minutes";
}
```

Comment: How would I make it so that it will say please come back in X minutes and X seconds? (if possible then JS dynamic countdown) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks soo much... Ill try to figure out how to use jquery to make it dynamic (countdown)... If you have any idea on how to do this, please do so... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

please check your database timezone and php timezone settings.

your timezone on the database and php maybe different.

on the php script you can use `date_default_timezone_set()` to set the timezone and `date_default_timezone_get()` to check what timezone is set

on mysql, look at `my.ini` or `my.cnf` for the settings